# CSS Sprite in a fluid layout

Tags: html, css, css-sprites, fluid-layout

I have a background image to be used for CSS sprite

[image]

Now the issue is I can only use fluid layout (only %, no px) and the % positioning creates an issue while resizing the browser (e.g. some portion of other arrow gets displayed)

How do I fix this ? Can i get an example of how to use % positioning for background ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A fluid layout and using fixed positioning are not mutually exclusive.

If you have an element on the page that does not expand, for example a button using a sprite background, then using `px` for size or position is appropriate (arguably mandatory).

Comment: As a more specific example, you can wrap the button element with the fixed width in a wrapper that has a % width. If you want the button element to be centered in the fluid dimensions of the wrapper, use an auto margin on the button element.

Comment: Could u just provide a very rough code abt what u r referring to for wrapper and % width..